# QtCreater cannot show ROS packges?

Tags: ros, qtcreator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use QtCreator to open the CMakeLists.txt (the root CMakeLists.txt) under the root `src/` folder. Normally, QtCreator should show the directory tree of all ROS packges as below:
[image: image description]
However, sometimes it fail to show the ROS packages, but turns out to be:
[image: image description]

This is very ugly and makes very inconvenient for me to find my desired source files and edit. So
anyone know why this situation happens and how to solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265962/qtcreater-cannot-show-ros-packges?/) by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2017-07-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What I really can recommend is the [ROS Qt Creator Plug-in](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_qtc_plugin/wiki/1.-How-to-Install-(Users)). Its a really nice plugin, where you can easily import ROS Workspaces via

`1. File > New File or Project > Import Project > Import ROS Workspace > Choose... 2. Enter a Project Name and Browse... to the ROS project workspace (workspace not src folder) then select Next >`

---

Originally posted by [chwimmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/21005/chwimmer/) with karma: 436 on 2017-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1